# (Lua) How do I break a string into entries on a table?

Tags: lua

So I want to take an input like R U R' U' and turn it into a table that contains

```
R
U
R'
U'
```

I haven't found an example of code that worked. I have tried [this](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/lua/lua+split+string+into+table) solution from codegrepper, and it didn't work. I have not come up with anything else in my head but my general program, which is supposed to take an input like R and find its place in a table. If R is 1, then it will take the value 1 from another table, which will have the r^ as value 1. Then it will do this with the rest and print it when it is done. So if there is an optimization with this that could make it all quicker than I would like to see it. Thanks and goodbye.

Comment: why do you say the code you tried didnt work? did you get an error or an undesired result? what was that result?

Comment: Please include enough code in your question to illustrate what you're trying to do. Do not post links to code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lua
function split(str, pat)
    local t = {}
    local fpat = "(.-)" .. pat
    local last_end = 1
    local s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, 1)
    while s do
        if s ~= 1 or cap ~= "" then table.insert(t, cap) end
        last_end = e + 1
        s, e, cap = str:find(fpat, last_end)
    end
    if last_end <= #str then
        cap = str:sub(last_end)
         table.insert(t, cap)
    end
    return t
end
```

then split it with split(var," ")

Answer (score 0):

```
local myString = "R U R' U'"
local myTable = {}

for e in string.gmatch(myString, "%S+") do
  table.insert(myTable, e)
end
```

> [Lua Users Wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial)
>
> s:gmatch(pattern)
>
> This returns a pattern finding iterator. The iterator will search
> through the string passed looking for instances of the pattern you
> passed.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to match all the space-separated parts. You can do this using `gmatch`. Then you can insert these parts as keys in a hash table, the value being the one-indexed index of the occurrence:

```lua
local str = "R U R' U'"
local index = 1
local last_occurrence = {}
for match in str:gmatch"%S+" do
    last_occurrence[match] = index
    index = index + 1
end
```

Now you can use your "other table" to obtain the value in constant time:

```lua
local other_table = {"r^"}
local value = other_table[last_occurrence.R] -- "r^"
```